# Store data from API request in a database or Shopify array variable

Tags: json, api, youtube, shopify, liquid

I'm using the Youtube API and store the response data with LocalStorage, then get the data from LocalStorage and do stuff (building the video carousel).

The ultimate goal is to avoid sending requests each time to the API and fetch the videos, as one query has 100 costs. Daily quotas are 10000.

So I'm looking for a way to make the request once daily then store the response in Shopify array and then build the carousel using that array.

**So my question is how to store the API response in a Shopify variable with {% assign %} if possible or to a database?**

Below is a snippet of the code

```
      let APIKEY = ""
      let channelId = ""
      let retrievedData = localStorage.getItem("FVideos");
      let newData = JSON.parse(retrievedData);
      let itemsArr = []; 

      if(newData == null){
            let request = $.ajax({
            url: `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=${APIKEY}&channelId=${channelId}&part=id&order=date&maxResults=6&fields=items(id(videoId))`,
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "json"
          });

          request.done(function( data ) {
          itemsArr.push(data.items);
            for(let i=0; i < data.items.length; i++){
              let videoId = itemsArr[0][i].id.videoId;
              createHtmlBlock(videoId);
              localStorage.setItem("FVideos", JSON.stringify(itemsArr));  
              } 
            })
          request.complete(function(){
            buildCarousel();
          })
          request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
              alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
          });

      } else {
        for( let d=0; d < newData[0].length; d++){
          let videoId = newData[0][d].id.videoId;
          createHtmlBlock(videoId);
        }

        buildCarousel();
     }
```

Comment: It's possible to store it in a metafield if you create a custom App with a cron job for example. Can you show us what have you tried on your own?

Comment: the answer is edited providing more information on this.